# SQL order by with case not ordering correctly

Tags: sql, vbscript

I have this simple SQL Select query:

```
SELECT part_number, bin_location FROM list ORDER BY bin_location
```

This will give me a result like this:

```
part_number       bin_location
Alaska wine           A1
German water          A2
London whisky         A3
German wine           A4
London water          B1
German wine           B2
London whisky         B3
German wine           C1
London whisky         C2
Water Green Wine      C3
Pure Water            D1
Orange whisky         D2
Ireland Moat          D3
French wine           XX
Italy water           XX
Water Green Wine      XX
Pure Water            XX
Orange whisky         XX
Ireland Moat          XX
French wine           XX
Italy water           XX
```

Now what i'm trying to do is order by bin_location and once bin_location equals xx order by part_number.

This is the query I am using to do this:

```
SELECT part_number,bin_location 
FROM list 
ORDER BY case when bin_location = 'xx' then part_number end
```

This is the result I get:

```
part_number       bin_location
Alaska wine           A1
German water          A2
London whisky         A3
German wine           C1
London water          A4
German wine           B2
London whisky         B3
German wine           A4
London whisky         C2
Water Green Wine      C3
Pure Water            D1
Orange whisky         D2
Ireland Moat          D3
French wine           XX
French water          XX
Ireland Moat          xx
Italy water           XX
Orange whisky         XX
Pure Water            XX
Water Green Wine      XX
```

As you can see after the xx clause is met it puts the part_number in order, but before this the bin location is not.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Rick, are the values `xx` and `XX` the same for the purpose of this query?

Comment: @Gordon - sorry forgot to mention it's an SQL db

Comment: @David - yes all the values in the db are xx, it just my typing error

Comment: @Rick, "SQL db" isn't meaningful. Do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: If a row with bin_location ZZ, should it appear before XX or after XX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT part_number, bin_location
FROM list
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN bin_location = 'xx' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),  -- put non-XX first
         (CASE WHEN bin_location <> 'xx' THEN bin_location END),
         part_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any need for a `CASE` statement. You can simply query as follows:

```
SELECT part_number, bin_location
  FROM list
 ORDER BY bin_location, part_number;
```

If you intend for `bin_location` to be case-insensitive (that is, `xx` and `XX` should be treated similarly), then you can do this instead:

```
SELECT part_number, bin_location
  FROM list
 ORDER BY UPPER(bin_location), part_number;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but there is not definition of when bin_location should stop the order and for part_number to take over, Once bin_location equals xx then order by part_number

Comment: Wait do you mean that for values of `bin_location` greater than or equal to `xx`, you then order by `part_number`?